# Repair Ubuntu after unsuccesful upgrading

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I was upgrading Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 12.04 and during this process I was using Google Chrome and some Nautilus windows and suddenly something came wrong (compiz or other package was updating...) X server wasn't responding. I had to restart my laptop because upgrading process wasn't going on. Since then Ubuntu doesn't stand up. After grub choise nothing shows (except blinking mouse pointer and purple background). I even can't switch to tty.

Enyone knows solution to that problem? How to repair this installation of Ubuntu. How get access to terminal (to diagnose, to check the system)?

Comment: Boot a live system from CD or USB drive and mount your hard drive(s). Then you can fix the system or restore your backup that you were advised to make before a major system upgrade.

Comment: The exact same thing happened to me just now. Doing the dist-upgrade trick right now. Let's wait and see if that works...

Comment: In the years since the XKCD cartoon on the subject, upgrading Ubuntu hasn't gotten much better

Answer (score 8):

In my case, after a crash during 11.10 to 12.04 upgrade, this command completed the upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade
```

, as suggested in https://askubuntu.com/a/122320.

About 600M of packages was downloaded and installed in the process.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [Ubuntu LiveCD Recovery Mode](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery). It gives you exactly what you need for repairing the system.